# How to align buttons at the bottom of the div with just CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the bellow code and as a newbie I'm struggling to make the button stay in line at the bottom of the div no matter how long the text above it is. I also want to keep the divs aligned at the top as well. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

edit: What I would like to achieve is something like how they did their packages (everything stays in place/buttons at the bottom of the box when the window is made smaller):
https://www.knownhost.com/

```css
.div1{width:90%;height:100%;max-width:1920px;margin:2.5em auto}
.div2{vertical-align:top;width:32%;margin:0 0 2em .5%;display:inline-block}
.image {background-color:#0d0d0d}
.image1{float:left;width:100%;border:1px solid #d7d7d7;margin-bottom: .8em}
.title{color:#55068f;font:20px robotoregular;text-align:center;padding:3em 0 0}
.text{width:85%;margin:1em auto 0;text-align:center;padding-bottom:34px;font:16px robotolight;height:auto;color:#313030;line-height:1.4em}
.button a,.button a:hover{text-decoration:none;margin:0 auto}
.button a{font:19px robotolight;color:#55068f;text-align:center;border:thin solid #55068f;padding:.8em 2em;width:40%}
.button a:hover{color:#0d0d0d;border:thin solid #FFD83A;background-color:#FFD83A}
.button{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="" class="image1" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class=content>
        <div class=title>Title</div>
        <div class=text><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
        </div>
        <div class=button><a href="" class=custom_btn>find out more</a></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="" class="image1" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class=content>
        <div class=title>Title</div>
        <div class=text><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy</div>
        </div>
        <div class=button><a href="" class=custom_btn>find out more</a></div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="" class="image1" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class=content>
        <div class=title>Title</div>
        <div class=text><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>
        </div>
        <div class=button><a href="" class=custom_btn>find out more</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like that? :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        
        .div1{
            width:90%;
            margin:2.5em auto;
        }

        .div2{
            vertical-align:top;
            width:32%;
            margin:0 0 2em .5%;
            display:inline-block;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .image {
            background-color:#0d0d0d
        }
        .image1{
            float:left;
            width:100%;
            border:1px solid #d7d7d7;
            margin-bottom: .8em
        }
        .title{
            color:#55068f;
            font:20px robotoregular;
            text-align:center;
            padding:3em 0 0
        }
        .text{
            width:85%;
            margin:1em auto 0;
            text-align:center;
            padding-bottom:34px;
            font:16px robotolight;
            height:auto;color:#313030;
            line-height:1.4em
        }
        .button a { 
            background-color: #fff; 
        }
        .button a,.button a:hover{
            text-decoration:none;margin:0 auto
        }
        .button a{
            font:19px robotolight;
            color:#55068f;
            text-align:center;
            border:thin solid #55068f;
            padding:.8em 2em;
            width:40%;
            
        }

        .button a:hover{
            color:#0d0d0d;
            border:thin solid #FFD83A;
            background-color:#FFD83A
        }
        .button{
            text-align:center;
        }

        .content { 
            position: relative;
            overflow-y: auto;
            display: inline;

         }

        .div1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        .div2 {
            height: 100%;

        }
        .div2-wrap {
            display: block;
            height: 90%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        .div2 .image {
            height: 40%;
        }
        .div2 .content {
            height: 50%;
        }
        .div2 .button {
            height: 10%;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        .div2 .button a {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: -6px;
        }
        #main {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div2-wrap">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="" class="image1" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class=content>
                <div class=title>Title</div>
                <div class=text><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500sLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500sLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500sLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class=button><a href="" class=custom_btn>find out more</a></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div2-wrap">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="" class="image1" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class=content>
            <div class=title>Title</div>
            <div class=text><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=button><a href="" class=custom_btn>find out more</a></div>
    </div>
        
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div2-wrap">
            <div class="image"><a href=""><img src="" class="image1" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class=content>
                <div class=title>Title</div>
                <div class=text><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=button><a href="" class=custom_btn>find out more</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <p>Put your content here</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but not the right solution. I want to keep the 2.5 em margin at the top and bottom for "div 1" not 0. Also the divs 2 are aligned at the top using "vertical-align:top" but I can't manage to make the buttons aligned at the bottom (right now they move up/down based on the text length).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you exactly want. Do you want to .div1 covered the whole screen and buttons to be aligned from bottom? If so I edited my post. You can try

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this still doesn't work for me. If you run the code snippet from my post you'll see an example with my issue (buttons not in line at the bottom). Your code works partially but the text just goes through the button when the page gets smaller. Also I don't need a fixed position for div1 as I have other content on my page and that messes it.

Comment: I rebuild your html struct little bit. You can place your other content into <div id="main"></div>

Comment: Thank you, this works but I don't want a scroll bar for the text. What I want to achieve is something more like they do here with the packages: https://www.knownhost.com/

Comment: You can but if you have longer text it will always overflow. You need to set strict height for it